# Conveying 'party animal'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> Sandy loves going to parties! She’s a real party animal.

A party animal = a person who loves partying.

> Sandy adore aller aux soirées ! C'est une vraie fêtarde.

What other idiomatic ways exist to express the idea of 'party animal'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think fêtard is the closest translation. Other ideas:

- If they party at night: [noctambule](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/noctambule/54742).
- If they focus on enjoying life: bon vivant (not exclusive to parties).
- [Bambocheur](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bambocheur/7759) is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Il exixte un terme qui n'est pas récent.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bambochard)) **bambochard** \bɑ̃.bɔ.ʃaʁ\ masculin (pour une femme, on dit : bambocharde)
>
> Celui qui aime la bonne nourriture, faire la fête, le plaisir.
>
> - C’était un sacré bambochard, je le vois encore festoyant et hilare.
> - Joyeux, lui aussi, malin à l’occasion, et bambochard, il [Guignol] a fort bon cœur s’il a mauvaise tête – et du bon sens, s’il est ignorant. — (Louis Guilloux, Chroniques de Floréal, 1922-1923, Héros limite, Paris, 2018)
> - Or, Maginot avait la réputation d’un joyeux bambochard, amateur de soupers nocturnes, et d’huîtres. — (Henry Charbonneau, Les Mémoires de Porthos, 1969)
>
> Synonymes :
> bambocheur (bambocheuse),
> fêtard;
> noceur,
> teufeur,

Tous ces termes, sauf « teufeur », concernent plus particulièrement les évènements dont l'attrait principal est la nourriture et les boissons (alcooliques) riches en gout.

Pour ce qui est des parties, où l'attrait est la musique, la danse populaire et les boisson alcooliques, et la drogue,  « teufeur » pourrait peut-être convenir, mais c'est du verlan , et c'est un terme qui réfère spécifiquement aux gens qui vont aux free parties (rave parties).

Comment: Il y a aussi bringueur/euse et l'expression "oiseau de nuit" qui pourrait faire écho à party animal

Comment: @qqjkztd « Oiseau de nuit » est trop restrictif, trop général ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oiseau) 4. Oiseau de nuit. Personne qui veille quand les autres dorment. ) (la nuit seulement, vivre en général). «Bringueur » est exagéré (débauché) mais pas si mauvais. Vous avez peut-être une réponse, à vous de  voir (TLFi à « bringueur » et autres dictionnaires).

Answer (score 1):

En complément à une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51787/26366), [*Larousse en ligne anglais-français*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/party_animal/600576) traduit « she's a real party animal » simplement par « elle adore faire la fête » ; moins informel mais que je trouve intéressant parce qu'on emploie le verbe *adorer* et l'idée de passion ou de vivacité plutôt qu'un nom (*animal*) pour connoter l'exubérance...